# insert form data into two tables with one submit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i want to insert customer name in one table by using customer id insert customer city in other table.
my code inserts only customer. the cities are not inserting

my console

> Started POST "/pages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-30 14:40:15 +0530
>   Processing by PagesController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"NfyA8PpA4wZIAOPX7fYstwvt2suXoTYgl9ep1M6yTSh6ZPX8lt+oOfPX6sFXGOuxTidVND6qaksz6iZ2enGj9g==",
>   "customer"=>{"name"=>"fgfg", "custcity"=>{"cityname"=>"2fg"}},
>   "commit"=>"submit"} Unpermitted parameter: custcity    (0.1ms)  begin
>   transaction   SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "customers" ("name",
>   "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "fgfg"],
>   ["created_at", 2017-01-30 09:10:15 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-01-30
>   09:10:15 UTC]]    (231.7ms)  commit transaction    (0.2ms)  begin
>   transaction    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/pages Completed 302 Found in 247ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 234.3ms)

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @customer, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
<%= label_tag("Customer") %>
<br>
<%= f.text_field(:name) %>
<br>
<%= f.fields_for @custcity do |c| %>
        <%= label_tag("City 1") %>
        <br>
        <%= c.text_field(:cityname) %>
        <br>
        <%= label_tag("City 2") %>
        <br>
        <%= c.text_field(:cityname) %>
        <br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= f.submit("submit") %>
<% end %>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(cust_params)
    if @customer.save
       session[:customer_id] = @customer.id

      #@custcity = Custcity.create(cityname: params[:customer][:cityname], cust_id: session[:customer_id])
      @custcity = Custcity.create({cityname: params[:customer][:cityname], cust_id: @customer.id})
      #@custcity.save
      redirect_to pages_path
    else
      redirect_to new_page_path
    end
  end

  private
  def cust_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :custcity => [])
  end
end
```

Comment: You should use strong nested parameters and define customer city params in strong parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong path to `:cityname` key. You've lost `:custcity`

```
@custcity = Custcity.create({cityname: params[:customer][:custcity][:cityname], cust_id: @customer.id})
```

Permit `cityname` too:

```
params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :custcity => [:cityname])
```

Comment: By idea, Customer and Custcity models should be linked with has_many association and you don't need to call `Custcity.create` manually.